# Crystal Report with Django Python

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, crystal-reports

Now I am working with Django Rest Framework and my requirement is to generate the report by using crystal reports or other tools but first will use crystal report.

My project used DRF as backend and React as frontend. I think React cant do like that kind of job so I am trying to do generate report as pdf from DRF and I will respond to react.

Now I am stuck how can I connect to crystal report from DRF? Please Help.

Comment: I don't think crystal report can be used with python/Django. your best bet will be using HTML to PDF conversion libraries like wkhtmltopdf

Comment: @ArunLaxman, Do u know another reporting tool than wkhtmotopdf?

Comment: There's Xhtml2pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding a Report Designer, maybe you can look into JasperReport, which supports data sources from JSON.
Via [pyreportjasper](https://github.com/PyReportJasper/pyreportjasper), you can generate the reports into PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use Crystal, you can create a "Report_Request" table in your database and insert into that table the necessary information (Report Name, parameter values, export format, export file name, email recipient(s), etc.).

A scheduled process can then monitor that table, trigger the generation of the report, and update a status column in that table. Your code can then redirect the user's browser to the result.

There are free/inexpensive 3rd-party Crystal Reports tools that can handle this type of automation, assuming you wish to avoid writing that code yourself. Ken Hamady provides a listing of 3rd-party Crystal Reports tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).